# how to start and Stop GPS by using code in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

i want enable GPS for 30sec when my application start (when  oncreate() method  calls ).  and after 30 sec it turn to disable mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code,

```
 LocationManager locationManager =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, WLConstants.DELAY_HOUR, gpsl
                        .getMinDistance(), gpsl);
```

and to stop the GPS try

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsl);
```

Give this after u complete ur time period.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);      
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            1,
            0,
            myLocationListener
    );
```